# VHDL package and std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying do declare a type to use in the port but i'm with a problem
if I do the following I get an error that STD_LOGIC_VECTOR isn't declared

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
-- Custom types --
package Common  is
    type Mem_in is array (2**6 to 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0); 
    type DinDout is range 11 downto 0;
end package Common ;
-- Use Custom Type
use work.Common.all;

entity MUX is

    Port (
        D       :   in Mem_in;
        Q       :   out DinDout;
        SEL     :   in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0)
        );
end MUX;
```

Why can't I use STD_LOGIC_VECTOR? If I change it to DinDout I get another problem down the line in the architecture: to_integer is not declared; indexed name is not a dindout.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
-- Custom types --
package Common  is
    type Mem_in is array (2**6 to 0) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0); 
    type DinDout is range 11 downto 0;
end package Common ;
```

And the entity using package Common:

```
-- Use Custom Type
use work.Common.all;

entity MUX is

    Port (
        D       :   in Mem_in;
        Q       :   out DinDout;
        SEL     :   in  DinDout
        );
end MUX;

architecture Arc of MUX is
begin
    Q <= D(to_integer(unsigned(SEL)));
end Arc;
```

how can I add STD_logic_vector to my package OR solve these two errors: to_integer is not declared; indexed name is not a dindout?

thanks

Comment: In addition to the MUX entity declaration missing context items in the preceding context clause your `Mem_in` array type has 2\*\*6 + 1  (2\*\*6 **downto** 0) elements which is going the same number of distinct indexes not 2\*\*DinDout'length causing a constraint violations for some values of SEL. Your memory size should be a power of 2 matching the length of SEL. It seems unusual to provide a port with so many 'bits' (2\*\*6+1 * 12 - the length of a memory element or 780.  This memory read MUX that should likely be located with the actual for D particularly for block memory.

Comment: Type DinDout is an abstract numerical type with a value range of 11 downto 0, while D(to_integer(unsigned(SEL))) is an indexed element of D which is an array of std_logic_vectors with an index range of 11 downto 0. They are different types. Note your accepted answer did not address *...OR solve these two errors:...indexed name is not a dindout?* You have multiple errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two library units in one file (if it is a single file you have quoted). While I am not sure what happens, I guess it restarts the context with every unit.

That would mean you have to repeat

`library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;`

before `use work.Common.all;`.

Also `2**6 to 0` is a null range, that should be `0 to 2**6` or `2**6 downto 0`.

Comment: thanks it worked, but now I have a problem here: D(to_integer(unsigned(SEL))); it says "indexed name is not a dindout". how can I index to get for example Mem_in( int( X ) ) x being 2**6 to 0?